# Code to get the output based on the input given in Jupyter Notebook using Python using input file as csv

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have csv file named Crops.
File consists 4 columns as mentioned below.

Temperature  PH   Humidity   Suitable crop to Grow
20.5     15      30.2           Paddy
21.5     16      26.6           Millets
23.5     17      23.4           Corn

So if the input given for Temperature, PH & Humidity is 23.5, 17 & 23.4 then the output should be displayed as Suitable crop to grow is 'Corn'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Pandas** for a quick way to do this

```
import pandas as pd

crops_data = pd.read_csv(FILEPATH)

temperature_input = float(input("Enter Temperature: "))
ph_input = float(input("Enter pH: "))
humidity_input = float(input("Enter Humidity: "))

data_filter = (crops_data["Temperature"] == temperature_input) & (crops_data["PH"] == ph_input) & (crops_data["Humidity"] == humidity_input)
suitable_crop = crops_data.loc[data_filter]["Suitable crop to Grow"].values[0]

print(suitable_crop)
```

Check out the [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) for more information on how to use it

---

Although, Pandas feels a bit overkill for such a simple task

So, you can directly read the CSV and make a few basic comparisons to get your data

```
CSV = []

with open(FILEPATH, 'r') as csv_file:
    CSV = csv_file.read().split()[1:]

temperature_input = float(input("Enter Temperature: "))
ph_input = float(input("Enter pH: "))
humidity_input = float(input("Enter Humidity: "))

filter_string = "%g,%g,%g" % (temperature_input, ph_input, humidity_input)
filter_result : str

for LINE in CSV:
    if filter_string in LINE:
        filter_result = LINE.split(',')[-1]

print(filter_result)
```

You can be a bit creative with the `filter_string` to get other results

Comment: i looking for something like this. enter temperature , enter PH , enter Humidity.  After giving inputs it has to print Output as The suitable crop is__

Comment: @PradeepGN That is just **Basic I/O**. Please consider **learning Python first** before jumping into a project. For the time being, please check the **edited answer for the solution**